# How to sort dates per year, month and dat in a dataframe

Tags: r, sorting, date, dataframe

If i have this dataframe A:

```
A:

1           date     X      Y
2     1948-01-01     0      0
3     1948-01-10     0      0
4     1948-01-11     0      0
5     1948-01-12     0      0
6     1948-01-13     0      0
7     1948-01-14     0      0
8     1948-01-15     0      0
9     1948-01-16     0      0
10    1948-01-17     0      0
11    1948-01-18     0      0
12    1948-01-19     0      0
13    1948-01-02     0      0
14    1948-01-20     0      0
15    1948-01-21     0      0
```

I need to sort the dates allowing the days being in order.. obtaining this:

```
A:

1           date     X      Y
2     1948-01-01     0      0
      1948-01-02     0      0
      1948-01-03     0      0
      1948-01-04     0      0
      1948-01-05     0      0
      1948-01-06     0      0
      1948-01-07     0      0
      1948-01-08     0      0
      1948-01-09     0      0
3     1948-01-10     0      0
4     1948-01-11     0      0
5     1948-01-12     0      0
6     1948-01-13     0      0
7     1948-01-14     0      0
8     1948-01-15     0      0
9     1948-01-16     0      0
10    1948-01-17     0      0
11    1948-01-18     0      0
12    1948-01-19     0      0 
14    1948-01-20     0      0
15    1948-01-21     0      0
```

Im trying this function:

```
A[order(as.Date(A$date,format="%y-%m-%d")),]
```

But is not working, any idea about how to solve it?

Comment: I am assuming you are using R so I added the R tag.

Comment: What exactly is not working (what is your error message or observed unexpected behaviour)?

Answer (score 0):

Try using instead

```
A[order(as.Date(A$date, format = "%Y-%m-%d")), ]
```

(note the capitalization of "%Y")

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if this is the most elegant solution in the world but it should work:

```
tt <- A$date
tt2 <- data.frame(ord = c(1:length(tt)),matrix(as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(tt,"-"))),ncol=3,nrow=length(tt),byrow=T))
tt2 <- tt2[order(tt2$X3,tt2$X2,tt2$X1),]

A <- A[tt2$ord,]
```